Accessing API in Node to the React NextJs throwing error
import _regeneratorRuntime from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/regeneratorRuntime";^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a moduleat wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1281:20)at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:27)at
Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
at mod.require (C\Users\UserName\Desktop\ReactApp\SocialMediaApp\client\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:65:28)at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
at rc-util/es/React/render (C\Users\UserName\Desktop\ReactApp\SocialMediaApp\client.next\server\pages\Register.js:322:18)at webpack_require (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\ReactApp\SocialMediaApp\client.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/antd/es/modal/confirm.js:14:81)
at ./node_modules/antd/es/modal/confirm.js (C\Users\UserName\Desktop\ReactApp\SocialMediaApp\client.next\server\vendor-chunks\antd.js:580:1)
at webpack_require (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\ReactApp\SocialMediaApp\client.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/antd/es/modal/index.js:5:66)
at ./node_modules/antd/es/modal/index.js (C\Users\UserName\Desktop\ReactApp\SocialMediaApp\client.next\server\vendor-chunks\antd.js:610:1)
 {page: '/Register'}
○ Compiling /_error ...✓ Compiled /_error in 1560ms (859 modules)GET /Register 500 in 5810ms

I tried to access the back-end using react NextJs but got an error because we are hitting the backend API file (.mjs) extension instead of .js to use the import one instead of the required
